# When using a static class method as a class decorator the `this` variable become undefined in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I want to use a static class method as class decorator as:

```js
class Decorator {
  public static deco(constructor: new() => any) {
    console.log(this);
    return constructor;
  }
}

function anotherDeco(constructor: new() => any) {
  return Decorator.deco(constructor);
}

// This one will output `undefined` which is unexpected
@Decorator.deco
class MyClass1 {
}

const instance1 = new MyClass1();

// The one will output `[class Decorator]` as expected
@anotherDeco
class MyClass2 {
}

const instance2 = new MyClass2();
```

I found the that if I directly use the static method, as `MyClass1`, then `this` in the method would become undefined. However, if I wrap it into a normal function everything goes fine but I don't want the redundant wrapper.

Is that possible to make the `MyClass1` example work?

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?experimentalDecorators=true#code/MYGwhgzhAEAiCmwD2AnMAXV0DeAoa0ADgK4BGIAlsNBOhldACaJIAUyAdrSscJigC5oHeAHdWASmgBeAHzQwHAJ5S8BApwhIQ8AHQgkAc1boAFhQgSA3PnUp46Yig7RN6Hn1Q2CAX1x-cADNiDj4KJBdFJDN4FARkdgjuXn4hEXEpOQVlVVt7R2c4FjR%20XWYEtw9%20a39cXAB6eugAFXMYCPhoUQoQEGgkYnQSdGgAAxDmQIoRRlGu82BTaAtoEPgAD0JEdHhGXAABeNQMVDKWXFBIGABZJQBhcCgARhxai6SR6dpFYHgX6WEYmgtweVyekhsDSarU6HS6PT6AyGgzGAG1LlAisgSqgALpzSDQDZbPi7A5RGJxc4Ym73R4QABMrwCbmWXDooXgTIB6WBdKuDIhQA)

Comment: As for the question, it's just the plain old regular handling of `this` [How does the "this" keyword work, and when should it be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3127429) | [How to access the correct `this` inside a callback](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20279484). Using `@Decorator.deco` doesn't magically bind the `this` value. Still depends on the execution.

Comment: Decorators are functions and are called as such (this is true for both legacy and new decorators, I think).  They are not bound to any containing object before being called.  So `@foo.bar` will not have `foo` as the `this` context in `bar`.  If you need that you'll have to rebind it yourself (such as wrapping in a standalone function).  I don't think this is anything TypeScript can do much about.

Comment: Does that mean I should provided a *bound* function instead of a plain static method?